# variable number of serialized arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I was wondering if there is a way to create a variable number of arrays with certain serialization, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < var; i++)
{
    int[] s"i" = new int[var2];
}
```

for "var" and "var2" = 1, 2, 3, ...

and having as a result, for example if "var" and "var2" = 2, two arrays s1[2] and s2[2].

Is this understandable? is there a way?

Comment: Create an array of arrays outside the loop!

Comment: You could create a `List<int[]>`, but what you are asking isn't possible. Just so you're aware, "serialization" is a completely different topic than what you are asking about.

Comment: Yes I understand that, just didn't find a better word to describe what i was asking. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# does not allow for this specific type of behavior as you've described it.  However, you do have the option of creating a list containing a variable number of arrays, which essentially accomplishes the same thing with more rigid syntax.

```
int var = 2;
int var2 = 2;
List<int[]> arrays = new List<int[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < var; i++)
{
    arrays.Add(new int[var2]);
}
```

The end result would be a list containing two arrays, each initialized to a length of two.

Comment: I think i get it, thak you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :).  As mentioned in the comments above, this has nothing to do with serialization.  Rather, this is solely in regards to array initialization.

Comment: Well I understand that, i found lots of treaths on serialization while looking for this, which sincerily i don't know what it is, just didn't find a better word to describe it. Thanks again!